# Optional vs. mandatory terminators in context-free grammar definition

Tags: language-agnostic, parsing, compiler-construction, context-free-grammar

In a book chapter about compilers, there's the following grammar definition and example code.

```
...
statement: whileStatement
           | ifStatement
           | ... // Other statement possibilities
           | '{' statementSequence '}'
whileStatement: 'while' '(' expression ')' statement
ifStatement: ... // Definition of "if"
statementSequence: '' // empty sequence (null)
                   | statement ';' statementSequence
expression: ... // Definition of "expression"
...             // More definitions follow
```

```
while (expression) {
 statement;
 statement;
 while (expression) {
  while(expression)
     statement;
  statement;
 }
}
```

How is the code's inner-most `while` loop valid without `{` `}`? It looks to me that the statement definition requires them. Is this a mistake in the book or am I misunderstanding the syntax?

---

**[Edit]** My apologies for any ambiguity. Everything typed above is verbatim from the book. The omissions were not my doing.

Comment: What are the "other statement possibilities"? One of them must match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider your example code again:

```
1 while (expression) {
2  statement;
3  statement;
4  while (expression) {
5   while(expression)
6      statement;
7   statement;
8  }
9 }
```

Why are you concerned that line 6 lacks braces, but don't care that lines 2, 3, and 7 are missing them too? The grammar is saying that a `while` loop ends with a `statement`, and a `statementSequence`, with its required braces, is just one of many alternatives for a `statement`. Lines 5 and 6 match that rule exactly—except for the `';'`, which doesn't have a place in the rule.

Comment: Ah! You're so right. I was focused on the fact that the only statement other than if and while used { } and ignoring that if "statement;" can be a self-contained placeholder in lines 2, 3, 7 then why not 6?

Answer (score 2):

Your while statement says that after the `)` comes a statement.  Your grammar doesn't fully specify `statement`, but it doesn't require braces.  Braces are only needed for a statement sequence.

Comment: Never the less it appears to be a small mistake in the book.  The missing possibilities for 'statement' could not include 'statement' itself, it would have to be 'simple_statement' or the like the example would have to use this rather that just 'statement'.

Comment: Well, there's a huge ambiguity here in the first place: In the code sample, what does the token "statement" even mean?  I assumed it meant: some uninteresting line that matches statement.